# use of undeclared identifier 'MAP_POPULATE'

Tags: c++, macos, mmap

When using mmap on Mac OS X and Xcode I am getting the error:

> use of undeclared identifier 'MAP_POPULATE'

The same code is working on another machine. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

`MAP_POPULATE` is available only on Linux and only since version 2.5.46 (since version 2.6.23 for private mappings). `MAP_POPULATE` is used to reduce the penalty of page faults, so your code should be able to run without. Here is an example of how you can use the preprocessor to run the same code on different machines.

```
#if __linux__
#include <linux/version.h>
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE > KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,22)
#define _MAP_POPULATE_AVAILABLE
#endif
#endif

#ifdef _MAP_POPULATE_AVAILABLE
#define MMAP_FLAGS (MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_POPULATE)
#else
#define MMAP_FLAGS MAP_PRIVATE
#endif
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem on mac M1.